# HandConstraint MRTK not detecting controller ray unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, mrtk, oculusquest

I am using the HandConstraint solver for MRTK with Solver Handler TrackedTargetType as Controller Ray. The documentation says that HandConstraint works both with Controllers and hands. When I use the application, the solver does not detect the controller until I once use my hand and then use the controller. How do I fix this? As I want it to work only with the controller. I am developing for **Oculus Quest 2** using MRTK.

This is my parameters set

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally solved it after reading the script and also some trial and error. All you need to do is tick the "Update When Opposite Hand Near" Box. Idk why this needs to be enabled for the controllers to work on first try but yeah, it does the work.

[image]